# Insert line if pattern doesn't match otherwise modify the line with the pattern

Tags: shell, sed

Suppose I want to modify a file `foo.ini` with the following `sed`:

```
bar="hello"

sed -i "                                                                                                                                                             
# if there is NZ variable in db2dj.ini, we simply set it to the proper value                                                                           
s/NZ=*/NZ=$bar/

# if there is no NZ variable, we add NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH variable and set the proper value to it                                                          
T add


:add
$ i\NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH=$db2dj_nz_odbc_ini_path

" foo.ini
```

Suppose `foo.ini` is empty at first. Then I run the `sed` above and I got:

```
NZ=hello
```

This is fine. However, if I run the same `sed` command again, `foo.ini` will become:

```
NZ=hellohello
NZ=hello
```

My ideal for `sed` command is that:

1. if there is no `NZ` variable, then it add `NZ=hello` to it
2. if there is already `NZ` variable with form like `NZ=hi`, it will change it to `NZ=hello`
3. Only when `NZ=hello` should appear in `foo.ini`

How do I modify the above `sed` command to achieve this task? I believe my `sed` command works fine with (1) but not with (2) (3)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `grep` check is sufficient:

```
grep -q '\bNZ=\b' foo.ini > /dev/null 2>&1 && sed -i 's/NZ=.*$/NZ=hello/' foo.ini || echo "NZ=hello" >> foo.ini
```

The above statement will insert if no variable present. Also it handles substitution if already present with a different/same value.

```
$ cat foo.ini
cat: foo.ini: No such file or directory
$ grep -q '\bNZ=\b' foo.ini > /dev/null 2>&1 && sed -i 's/NZ=.*$/NZ=hello/' foo.ini || echo "NZ=hello" >> foo.ini
$ cat foo.ini 
NZ=hello
$ grep -q '\bNZ=\b' foo.ini > /dev/null 2>&1 && sed -i 's/NZ=.*$/NZ=hello/' foo.ini || echo "NZ=hello" >> foo.ini
$ cat foo.ini 
NZ=hello
$ vim foo.ini 
$ cat foo.ini 
NZ=hi
$ grep -q '\bNZ=\b' foo.ini > /dev/null 2>&1 && sed -i 's/NZ=.*$/NZ=hello/' foo.ini || echo "NZ=hello" >> foo.ini
$ cat foo.ini 
NZ=hello
```

Comment: If `foo.ini` is empty, then the command doesn't add `NZ=hi` to `foo.ini` Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks much for the help!